# DBLINK vs Postgres_FDW, which one may provide better performance?

Tags: postgresql, dblink, postgres-fdw

I have a use case to distribute data across many databases on many servers, all in postgres tables.
From any given server/db, I may need to query another server/db.
The queries are quite basic, standard selects with where clauses on standard fields.

I have currently implemented postgres_FDW, (I'm, using postgres 9.5), but I think the queries are not using indexes on the remote db. 
For this use case (a random node may query N other nodes), which is likely my best performance choice based on how each underlying engine actually executes?

Comment: upgrade to 9.6 or better to 10. The ability to push predicates and work  to  the remote server has been improved substantially since 9.5

Comment: *I think the queries are not using indexes on the remote db*: find out the remote query with `EXPLAIN` and use `EXPLAIN` on the remote database to get the execution plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was simple: I upgraded to Postgres 10, and it appears to push where clauses down to the remote server.

Comment: To anyone who cares, if you are using datatypes from postgis (geometry etc) you will have to declare that extension in the foreign server definition, or the conditions in teh where clause will NOT be pushed to the remote server

Comment: Did you have to use Postgres_fdw or blink to access the remote server?

Comment: I'm just pissed it's not passing window functions down... oh well

Answer (score 11):

> The Postgres foreign data wrapper (postgres_FDW) is newer to
>   PostgreSQL so it tends to be the recommended method. While the
>   functionality in the dblink extension is similar to that in the
>   foreign data wrapper, the Postgres foreign data wrapper is more **SQL
>   standard compliant and can provide improved performance over dblink
>   connections**.

Read this article for more detailed info: [Cross Database queryng](https://www.compose.com/articles/cross-database-querying-in-compose-postgresql/)